# How to add property to object using bracket notation for object and string for property name?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, parameters, notation

I would like to use bracket notation for writing the object name so that I can reference it via a parameter. That's fine, but I run into trouble when I try to write the property name without passing it as a parameter. It's important that the property name is simply written out and not passed as a parameter. What is the correct syntax?

This example shows all of the syntax variations that I have tried:

```js
var foo = {};

bar('foo', 'cat');
function bar(object, prop) {
    
    // foo[prop] = 5; // = 5. This works, but this isn't the method I want to use. 
    
    // [object]cat = 5; // = error
    // [object].cat = 5; // = undefined
    // [object]['cat'] = 5; // = undefined
    // [object][cat] = 5; // = error
    
    console.log('= ' + foo.cat);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `foo` is declared as a global variable, the window object will contain that object internally.

So, you can do the following:

```
window[object]['cat'] = 5;
```

```js
var foo = {};

bar('foo');
console.log('= ' + foo.cat);
function bar(object) {
    window[object]['cat'] = 5;            
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically trying not to write the property name as a passed parameter, which is what you are doing with `[prop]`.

Comment: @forestkelley so, you can do the following: `window[object]['cat'] = 5;`

Comment: That does work, thanks. Why do I need to use `window`? I feel like I've never had to do that before when accessing an object inside a function.

Comment: @forestkelley because there is no such thing as a dynamic variable name accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the actual object reference in:

```js
var foo ={}

bar(foo, 'cat', 3);

console.log('updated foo', foo);

function bar(object, prop, val) {
    object[prop] = val;      
    console.log('= ' + foo.cat);
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to pass the reference in. I'm simply trying to write the property name as a string instead of passing that in. @Ele has found a solution in his comment.

Comment: So you know you want to work with the `foo` object inside bar? Still a bit vague as to what you actually need

Answer (score -1):

```
function bar(object, prop) {
  this[object] = this[object] || {};
  this[object][prop] = 5;
  console.log(foo.cat)
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: `this` can be different things in different environments when not used in  a `new` context